# Testing for nontrivial evaluation

Tags: expression-test, hold

How can I tell programmatically if a function has evaluated in a nontrivial way?

I'd like to do, essentially, something along the lines of `f[x]===HoldForm[f[x]]`, a test that returns true if `f[x]` just evaluates to `f[x]` because it's not defined, or else false if `f[x]` actually does something. Of course, that example code doesn't work - my guess is that the HoldForm is printing itself or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f[x] === HoldForm[f[x]]` does not provide the desired result, because `HoldForm` stays attached to `f[x]` on the right side of the expression.
Thus, the left and right sides never are identical.  Instead use,

```
f[x] === Unevaluated[f[x]]
(* True *)
```

And, when the function does something,

```
g[x_] := x^2
g[x] === Unevaluated[g[x]]
(* False *)
```

`Unevaluated` prevents evaluation only on a single line, then goes away, so it works for this purpose.